# Exception in JAX-RS with RESTEASY with TOMCAT 7

Tags: resteasy

I am trying to implement a RESTFULL service with RESTEASY. When I am trying to run in Tomcat Server 7.0, iam getting exception. Please find the details below.

Error Message

> May 15, 2016 11:10:33 PM org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler
>   handleWebApplicationException ERROR: RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute
>   javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource
>   for full path:
>   http://localhost:8080/RestEasyHello/service/HelloRestEasy/response/
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:75)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:445)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:254)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:191)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Service Code:

```
package com.naresh.resteasy;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/HelloResteasy")
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public class HelloService {

    @GET
    @Path("/response")
    public String printResponse(){
        return "Hello";

    }

}
```

Code for Service Class Implementation

```
package com.naresh.resteasy;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

-------------------------
@ApplicationPath("/service")
public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public HelloApplication() {
        singletons.add(new HelloService());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

}
```

Web-XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>RestEasyHello</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.naresh.resteasy.HelloApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Below dependency is for JAXB integration -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `@Path` annotation is a case-sensitive string. In your service code, `HelloService` is annotated with `@Path("/HelloResteasy")`, but your request path is `http://localhost:8080/RestEasyHello/service/HelloRestEasy/response/`

The @ApplicationPath defines the relative base URL path for all JAX-RS services in the deployment. So, in your code, all of JAX-RS RESTful services should be prefixed with the `/services` path when you execute. That is, `http://localhost:8080/service/HelloRestEasy/response/`

Comment: Thanks Rahman for the response. I tried with the correct Resource URL, but getting the same exception.   May 16, 2016 12:50:56 PM org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler handleWebApplicationException
ERROR: RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/RestEasyHello/service/HelloResteasy/response/
 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:75)